# Python sort_values plot is inverted

Tags: python, plot

new Python learner here. This seems like a very simple task but I can't do it to save my life.

All I want to do is to grab 1 column from my DataFrame, sort it, and then plot it. THAT'S IT. But when I plot it, the graph is inverted. Upon examination, I find that the values are sorted, but the index is not...

Here is my simple 3 liner code:

```
testData = pd.DataFrame([5,2,4,2,5,7,9,7,8,5,4,6],[9,4,3,1,5,6,7,5,4,3,7,8])
x = testData[0].sort_values()
plt.plot(x)
```

edit:
Using matplotlib

Comment: You should always include which plotting library you're using in questions like these.

Comment: As for 'inverted graph' - I presume you mean that Pandas is displaying it as values on the y-axis vs. index on the x-axis. This is completely normal behaviour. IF you want to change it, just do something like `plt.plot(x, range(len(x)))` to explicitly specify that `x` should be treated as an x-axis variable and the corresponding indices as y-axis values.

Comment: looks like matplotlib to me

Comment: Yes, sorry all, it's matplotlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about ordering values sequentially on the x-axis like 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ... You need to re-index your values.

```
x = testData[0].sort_values()
x.index = range(len(x))
plt.plot(x)
```

[image: re-indexed values]

Other than that if you want your values sorted in the data frame but displayed by order of index then you want a scatter plot not a line plot

```
plt.scatter(x.index, x.values)
```

[image: scatter plot]